# Invalid PNG when training ResNet but no info on which file is corrupted

Tags: image, tensorflow, png

I am training a ResNet (from scratch) on a large collection (>1 M) images.

However when it starts training (model.fit) it fails with

```
Invalid PNG. Failed to initialize decoder.
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2506]
```

I understand the error but I already removed all 0 sizes images (find . -size 0c -delete) and check for size (everything same size). So long story short, is there a way to point to the faulty image/images?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using a cavemen approach

```
find . -size -100k -delete
```